# Internal Server error while adding documents Solr

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, solr, nutch

I use urls to crawl sites and get data from those sites.....I use solr 3.4.0 and nutch 1.9.
    It was working fine but now suddenly from last week I am getting this error:

```
 2015-06-18 18:32:49,718 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: site dest: site
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2015-06-18 18:32:53,531 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2015-06-18 18:32:54,484 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Adding 1000 documents
2015-06-18 18:34:34,156 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0030
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

request: http://host IP:port/solr/news/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:49)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.write(SolrWriter.java:81)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:440)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:166)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
2015-06-18 18:34:35,062 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
2015-06-18 18:34:35,140 INFO  solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates - SolrDeleteDuplicates: starting at 2015-06-18 18:34:35
2015-06-18 18:34:35,140 INFO  solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates - SolrDeleteDuplicates: Solr url: http://Host IP:Port/solr/news
2015-06-18 18:36:52,718 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0031
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:178)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat$1.next(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:270)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat$1.next(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
```

Anybody who can help me remove this error.Thanks in advance.

The solr log gives me this error:org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter finalize
SEVERE: SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(), indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock

Comment: The Solr log is probably more useful than the Nutch log, as the Solr server seems to be responding with a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Where will be the Solr log file located?

Comment: I got the solr log file

Comment: What is the solution to 500 Internal Server Error.